# How the Firebase Firestore's snapshots() is made and how it can listen to the database updates with a stream inside the flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, real-time

in the `snapshots()` method that returns a `Stream` of document or collection snapshots from Firestore's database:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collection").snapshots();
```

How the stream is done, I mean what should I know and learn in order to make as an example a `Stream` that will listen to endpoint/database changes?

I have an idea about using web sockets but I don't think this is what it's used in the `snapshots()`.

and I don't want some way to create a `Stream` that requests new data every n `Duration`.

I want something that does nothing when nothing happens in the backend, but once we change something the `Stream` should know about it and listen to it.

Thank you!

Comment: The question describes the built-in basic functionality of [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). You are notified of changes when something happens, otherwise there's no interaction between the server and your app. The interaction between your app and Firestore is very well covered in the documentation [Listen for Changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) So. What are you asking? Can you clarify the question or include the code you're having difficulty with? See [Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter?hl=en#0)

Comment: I am asking how can I achieve the same thing the snapshots() do with my own backend server. I don't have a code issue, I want to know how and what is used to connect between the backend server and the flutter client project to make a Stream of data responses

Comment: *how can I achieve the same thing the snapshots() do* - sounds like you're asking us how to create your own SDK that offers snapshot functionality for a server of some kind. That's unrelated to Firebase itself and really goes well beyond what we can answer here. *I don't have a code issue* - SO *is* for coding specific issues; see [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This would probably be better asked on serverfault or maybe reddit

Answer (score 0):

You have the first part right already. Store it in a variable.

```
final myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collection").snapshots();
```

Next, you need to use a StreamBuilder pass in your stream

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: myStream,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot response) {
if(response.connectionState==Connectionstate.waiting) return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    final data = response.data();
    return WidgetToDisplayData()
```

}
),

Pass all the other required arguments including the builder widget, which refers to what you want. Firebase has a caching mechanism that ensured a listener is only active if there are changes detected in the db

Comment: Hi, thank you for the effort, but I don't think you read the question.